# Nth Occurrence in HLOOKUP/INDEX

Tags: excel, vba, function, vlookup

I want to find the 2nd non-zero occurrence in a row.

[image]

i.e, get the value (a,d) in return when i search for non-zero values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to find the 2nd non-zero occurrence in a row.

you can do this via INDEX/MATCH when used with SMALL for an array which shows ROWs/COLUMNs. Then simply offset the k for SMALL with COUNTIF to skip the zeros like this:

```
=INDEX(A2:F2,,SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(COLUMN(A1:F1)*(A1:F1<>0),COUNTIF(A1:F1,0)+2)))
```

To get earlier or later values: simply change the `+2` part to the number of occurrence you want to output.

Or as a shorter faster array-formula:

```
{=INDEX(A2:F2,,SMALL(IF(A1:F1<>0,COLUMN(A1:F1)),2))}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked :)